# Does BCl4- exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis

Is [BCl4-] a good Lewis acid as I according to Jerry March's Advanced Organic Chemistry ,the reactivity order of Lewis acids in Friedel Craft reactions , BCl3 is mentioned which means that BCl4- is a Lewis acid . Then why on hydrolysis of BF3, HBF4 is formed and on hydrolysis of BCl3 [BCl4-] does not show up?

Comment: Could you provide the page numbers (and edition) from Jerry March's Advanced Organic Chemistry or any other authentic sources for (1) Friedel-Craft Reaction with $\ce{BCl3}$ as Lewis acid and (2) Hydrolysis of $\ce{BF3}$?

Comment: There are [several dozens of refined crystal structures with $\ce{[BCl4]-}$](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Compound=tetrachloroborate&DatabaseToSearch=Published), so the answer to the title question is apparently yes. I'm not sure though I follow the logic in the question body: how exactly Friedel–Craft**s** reaction is involved in this (maybe cite the exact page and edition of the book)? Hydrolysis of $\ce{BF3}$ is heavily temperature-dependent, and $\ce{H[BF4]}$ exists only in diluted $\ce{HF}$ as the product above 20 °C. Also, **L**ewis is the scientist's *name*.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try a different solvent. Boron-chlorine bonds tend to be broken up by water but [not by liquid sulfur dioxide[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/j150581a040). In sulfur dioxide solvent the formation of $\ce{BCl4^-}$ accounts for the increased solubility of potassium chloride when boron trichloride is present. In the reference this synthesis is carried out by adding successively larger amounts of boron trichloride to an equilibrium mixture of solid potassium chloride with the saturated solution of this salt in the liquid sulfur dioxide at $0°$C.

**Reference**

1. D. E. Burge, H. Freund, and T. H. Norris (1959). "The Formation of Tetrachloroborate Ion in Liquid Sulfur Dioxide Solution". *J. Phys. Chem.* **63**, 11, 1969–1971. https://doi.org/10.1021/j150581a040